# Convert JSON data into new JSON output

Tags: javascript, json, timestamp

I'm trying to write a script to output JSON according to these constraints. 
So far I think my logic is correct.

Any help is appreciated.

**CURRENT ISSUES:**

- [**working now**]I can't figure out why duration continues to return 0
- [**working now**]how to tackle setting the `max/min`
- tackling how to handle when two excursions of different types occur back to back (“hot” ⇒ “cold” or “cold” ⇒ “hot”)

This is how each new object should appear

```
  let current_excursion = {
      'device_sensor' : '',
      'start_at' : [],
      'stop_at' : 0,
      'duration' : 0,
      'type': '',
      'max/min':0
}
```

**device_sensor**
The `sId` this excursion was detected on.

**start_at**
The date and time the temperature first is out of range in `ISO_8601 format`.

**stop_at**
The date and time the temperature is back in range in `ISO_8601 format`.

**duration**
The total time in seconds the temperature was out of range.

**type**
Either the string “hot” or “cold” depending on the type of excursion.

**max/min**
The temperature extreme for the excursion. For a “hot” excursion this will be the max and for a “cold” excursion the min.

A temperature excursion event starts 
when the temperature goes out of range and ends when the temperature returns 
to the range.
For a “hot” excursion this is when the temperature is greater than 8 °C,
and for a “cold” excursion this is when the temperature is less than 2 °C.
 If two excursions of different types occur back to back
 (“hot” ⇒ “cold” or “cold” ⇒ “hot”) please take the midpoint of the two 
timestamps as the end of the first excursion and the start of the second.

If an excursion is occurring at the end of the temperature readings
 please end the excursion at the last reading (duration = 0)

Here is the link to the test data
[Test Case Data](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=2d467891c5b4488499cb2f24ee1543e6)

Here is what I've written so far:

```
const tempTypeTernary = (num) =>{
    if(num < 2){
      return 'cold'
    } else if(num > 8){
      return 'hot'
    }
}

const excursion_duration = (x,y) =>{
  let start = new Date(x) / 1000
  let end =  new Date(y) / 1000

  return end - start
}

const reset_excursion = (obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    if (obj[key] instanceof Array) obj[key] = []
    else obj[key] = ''
  })
}


const list_excursion = (array) =>{

  let result = [];
  let max_min_excursion = 0;
  let current_excursion = {
      'device_sensor' : '',
      'start_at' : [],
      'stop_at' : 0,
      'duration' : 0,
      'type': '',
      'max/min':0
}

  for(let k = 0; k < array.length;k++){

    if( array[k]['tmp'] < 2 || array[k]['tmp'] > 8){

      current_excursion['device_sensor'] = array[k]['sId'];
      current_excursion['start_at'] = [new Date(array[k]['time']).toISOString(),array[k]['time']];
      current_excursion['type'] =  tempTypeTernary(array[k]['tmp']);

      if( array[k]['tmp'] > 2 || array[k]['tmp'] < 8){
        current_excursion['stop_at'] = new Date(array[k]['time']).toISOString();
        current_excursion['duration'] = excursion_duration(current_excursion['start_at'][1],array[k]['time'])
          }
          result.push(current_excursion)
          reset_excursion(current_excursion)
      }


  }
  return result
}

list_excursion(json)
```

Comment: What does `tempTypeTernary` return when temp. is within range?

Comment: shouldn't the second if-clause be `if( array[k]['tmp'] > 2 && array[k]['tmp'] < 8)` instead of `if( array[k]['tmp'] > 2 || array[k]['tmp'] < 8)`?  And I think you have misplaced some curly brackets for the two if-clauses, or rather forgot to end the first with a curly brace, rendering the second useless.

Comment: @Roadowl currently it doesn't return anything when it's in range. because from my understanding I should only care if it's not in range then update the object. Do you think it should return something? if so why I'm curious

Comment: @Roadowl I thought the same thing about the second if clause, but when I did that before it didn't update `duration` and `stop_at`

Comment: I don't understand your if-clauses. In the first you're testing smaller 2 larger 8; let's say it's 9 (we know that that is 'hot'), so that if-clause evaluates to TRUE.  Stuff is done, but then your second if-clause kicks in as well. That tests >2 OR <8. Our value was 9, so that also evaluates to TRUE (because 9 > 2).  Note that nowhere are you testing for the value to be in the range 2..8, which is fine, but your second if-clause seems to me senseless and wrong.

Comment: I think what you want is just to have an else-clause hanging off the first if-clause (meaningn in essence: the value's good), and there do the calculation of the excursion.

Comment: So you can basically change the entire second if-line into `else` (add a curly close brace first), and there do the caluclations that you already have now.

Comment: So: `... ... tempTypeTernary(array[k]['tmp']);  } else { current_excursion['stop_at'] = new ... etc.`.  That also makes my earlier question about the function moot.

Comment: I hope that works -- I'm only eyeballing the code here.

Comment: @Roadowl Okay I understand what you're saying about the else clause.

Answer (score 0):

Let me be bold and try to answer on just eyeballing the code; please tryout this:

```
const tempTypeTernary = (num) =>{
    if(num < 2){
      return 'cold'
    } else if(num > 8){
      return 'hot'
    }
}

const excursion_duration = (x,y) =>{
  let start = new Date(x) / 1000
  let end =  new Date(y) / 1000

  return end - start
}

const reset_excursion = (obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    if (obj[key] instanceof Array) obj[key] = []
    else obj[key] = ''
  })
}


const list_excursion = (array) =>{

  let result = [];
  let max_min_excursion = 0;
  let current_excursion = {
      'device_sensor' : '',
      'start_at' : [],
      'stop_at' : 0,
      'duration' : 0,
      'type': '',
      'max/min':0
}


  for(let k = 0; k < array.length;k++){

    if( array[k]['tmp'] < 2 || array[k]['tmp'] > 8)
    {
      if (current_excursion['type']==null)
      {
          current_excursion['device_sensor'] = array[k]['sId'];
          current_excursion['start_at'] = [new Date(array[k]['time']).toISOString(),array[k]['time']];
          current_excursion['type'] =  tempTypeTernary(array[k]['tmp'])
      }
    }
    else    // this is where the second 'if' was
    {
      if (current_excursion['type']!=null)
      {
          current_excursion['stop_at'] = new Date(array[k]['time']).toISOString();
          current_excursion['duration'] = excursion_duration(current_excursion['start_at'][1],array[k]['time'])

          result.push(current_excursion)
          reset_excursion(current_excursion)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you explain why you included a `null` check at the end?

Comment: To see if a timer is currently running. If it is, now that the values are within range, it has to be stopped.  If it was null, no timer would be running, and this would be a continuation of a normal state, where the temp. is within normal range ([2..8]).

Comment: Btw., you should try if you need to check for `null` or if you need to check for `''`. I think the latter, so the test then become `if ...==''` and `if ...!=''`.

Comment: thank you for that explanation. Do you have any ideas on how to solve the last issue I listed?